# Failed to open browser while using line server in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting "Server is started at 5500 but failed to open browser. Try to change the CustomBrowser settings." in VScode while using line server. I have tried to change default settings but i still can't solve it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In VScode go to extension (ctrl+shift+x) and search for live server, on live server go to manage > extension setting, then look for `Live Server > Settings:Use Browser Preview` section in the settings.
If the checkbox is checked, uncheck it.